how to create a random algorithm to create an svg image that emulate military mimetic path
I would like to create a military mimetic background in a SVG image, using an algorithm maybe in JS, or by other solutions, that generates a random asymmetric geometries.
The goal is to get something like this:

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="a">
        <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency=".02" numOctaves="3" />
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 1" />
            <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 1 1" />
            <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1" />
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feColorMatrix values="1 0 0 0 0 
                          -1 1 0 0 0 
                          -1 -1 1 0 0 
                           0 0 0 0 1" />
        <feColorMatrix values="-.08 .42 .09 0 .08 
                           -.17 .35 -.08 0 .17 
                           -.08 .15 -.04 0 .08 
                           0 0 0 0 1" />
    </filter>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#a)" />
</svg>


In summary, I used feTurbolence filter in a SVG image to create a noise.
I change the color for each channel RGB as I like inspired by military mimetic texture.
I am wondering if there is a smarter or easier idea to get the same mimetic military effect.


Shapes had to extend beyond the canvas to not be weirdly inside
Shapes had to be curtailed in size
Shapes had to be distributed to not have one colour dominate

I do not know how to make the shapes "dirty" - perhaps use some transparency and a "dirty" background
Also I did not succeed in making them follow the edge of some neighbours.


// Helper function to shuffle an array
const shuffleArray = (array) =>
  array.map((value) => ({
    value,
    sort: Math.random()
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
  .map(({
    value
  }) => value);

const generateMimeticSVG = (width, height, numShapes) => {
  const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  const colors = ["#4b5320", "#8b4513", "#000000", "#c0c0c0"]; // Green, Brown, Black, Beige
  const shapesPerColor = Math.floor(numShapes / colors.length); // Equal distribution
  const shuffledColors = shuffleArray(
    Array.from({
      length: shapesPerColor
    }, () => colors).flat()
  );
  const maxSize = 150; // Maximum size for shapes in pixels

  // Generate a random point 
  const randomPoint = (centerX, centerY, maxSize) => ({
    x: centerX + (Math.random() - 0.5) * maxSize + (Math.random() - 0.5),
    y: centerY + (Math.random() - 0.5) * maxSize + (Math.random() - 0.5),
  });

  
  const createPath = (points) =>
    points.reduce(
      (d, point, i, arr) => {
        if (i === 0) return `M ${point.x},${point.y} `;
        const cp = {
          x: (arr[i - 1].x + point.x) / 2 + (Math.random() - 0.5),
          y: (arr[i - 1].y + point.y) / 2 + (Math.random() - 0.5),
        };
        return `${d}Q ${arr[i - 1].x},${arr[i - 1].y} ${cp.x},${cp.y} `;
      },
      ""
    ) +
    `Q ${points[points.length - 1].x},${points[points.length - 1].y} ${(points[0].x + points[points.length - 1].x) / 2},${(points[0].y + points[points.length - 1].y) / 2} Z`;

  const svg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
  svg.setAttribute("width", width);
  svg.setAttribute("height", height);
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);
  svg.style.backgroundColor = "#4b5320"; // Base military green

  // Generate shapes
  Array.from({
    length: numShapes
  }).forEach((_, i) => {
    const centerX = Math.random() * width;
    const centerY = Math.random() * height;
    const points = Array.from({
        length: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3
      },
      () => randomPoint(centerX, centerY, maxSize)
    );

    const path = document.createElementNS(ns, "path");
    path.setAttribute("d", createPath(points));
    path.setAttribute("fill", shuffledColors[i % shuffledColors.length]);
    path.setAttribute("opacity", 0.7); // opacity to blend 
    svg.appendChild(path);
  });

  return svg;
};

const svgContainer = document.getElementById("svg-container"); 
const mimeticSVG = generateMimeticSVG(800, 600, 450); // 800x600 canvas, 450 shapes
svgContainer.appendChild(mimeticSVG);
<div id="svg-container" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></div>




I found out the filter, the feTurbulence and the feColorMatrix tags a valuable option.
